# How to change start time using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-recording

I am recording a live stream to .ts file. But when I run this file through ffmpeg using

```
ffmpeg -i myRecordedFile.ts
```

it gives me wrong start time which is way out of the range. For example, my file's duration is 45 minutes but ffmpeg returns start 18910.272911

[image]

Is there a way to change the start value of a video file?

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg is simply telling you the starting timestamp as parsed from the input. MPEG-TS is a transport stream format, used to convey television broadcasts..etc, having no global header, and can be sliced at ~arbitrary points. There are timestamp packets (PCR) at regular intervals, and ffmpeg is showing you the timestamp of the earliest packet.

If you want your TS to have a start time of 0, you'll have to remux it.

```
ffmpeg -i myRecordedFile.ts -map 0 -c copy -muxpreload 0 -muxdelay 0 newFile.ts
```

..but this is unnecessary.

Comment: I think `ffmpeg` will make the starting timestamp 0 even without `-map` and the mux* options, at least for single audio streams, unless you use `-copyts`.